# Gruntfile - save compiled file to same directory as where the orignal was found

Tags: gruntjs

I've added a task to compile all slim templates:

```
// Watch and compile slim files
slim: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '*****[ALL DIRECTORIES]*****',
      src: ['{,*/}*.slim'],
      dest: '*****[WHICHEVER DIRECTORY FILE WAS FOUND IN]*****',
      ext: '.html'
    }]
  }
},
```

What I want to be able to do,  as per the pseudo code above, is compile ANY .slim file in ANY directory, then save the compiled HTML file into the same directory as the .slim file being edited.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just set `cwd` and `dest` to your root directory (or whatever directory you want), and filter slim-files in `src`.

unless you set the `flatten` option to true, the directory-structure will be preserved:

```
slim: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '.',
      src: '**/*.slim'
      dest: '.',
      ext: '.html'
    }]
  }
},
```